# how can i show the sent text to server in a textbox

Tags: c#

I send a text as byte[] to a server. In receive method, I want to show this bytes in a textbox.I use socket in my code .how can i do it? 
this is my code.My problem is buffer in receive method is null while I want to have the text that i sent to server also I want to show this text in a textbox in try block.

```
   protected void receive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ip = TextBox2.Text;
    IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipa, 50000);
    socket.Connect(endPoint);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    // length of the text "Hello world!"
    try
    {
        int iRx= socket.Receive(buffer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /* ... */ }
}
protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ip = "192.168.0.109";
    IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipa, 50000);
    socket.Connect(endPoint);
    try
    {
        string str = "Hello word";
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        socket.Send(byData);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
//After Catch
String recievedText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
textboxOutput.Text = recievedText; //Assuming textbox is called textboxOutput
```

You have a byte array containing the string you sent in ASCII format and so you can just call the GetString function to convert it to it's string state.

#### EDIT

The problem that you are currently having is actually due to the fact that in TCP connections you need one computer to act as a server and wait for a connection and the other as a client connecting to the server.
See example from microsoft on TCP listener: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener This will show you how to set up the server side.

Comment: when i debug my code,in try block in receive method i have a Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Was this on the server or client side?